# How to distinguish between Custom Objects and Platform Events when querying the CustomObject table?

Tags: custom-object, tooling-api, platform-event

The `CustomObject` table that can be accessed via the Tooling API includes [fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customobject.htm) like:

- NamespacePrefix
- DeveloperName

that provide enough information for a Custom Object API name to be constructed as e.g. `myns__MyName__c`.

Platform Events (that also appear in this table) require a `__e` suffix not a `__c` suffix, but I don't see any field that signals that apart from the fragile convention that the the `DeveloperName` ends in `Event`.

Am I missing something here?

(I have some permission set filtering logic driven by `CustomObject` and `CustomField` and this problem is making the code ugly.)

Comment: So... I'm going out on a limb here, but I think this is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). My reasoning is that you're trying to determine something you can't possibly determine from the API you've chosen as your source of data. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? What's the context (e.g. Apex, a web app, etc)?

Comment: FYI @sfdcfox: The context is Apex where I am filtering out objects and fields from permission sets contained in one managed package (A) to match the objects and fields present in some depended on managed packages (X, Y, Z). The behaviour of A degrades with earlier versions of X, Y, Z but A still needs to be installable. The permission sets are held in A as static resources and filtered as in the question here via a Setup page. There are many version permutations of X, Y, Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can distinguish Platform Events from other custom objects solely with queries against the Tooling API `CustomObject`.

What you could to is take the DurableId's for the records of interest and query for them against [`EntityDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm).

As you say, you could then identify the Platform Events by their `__e` suffix or that they KeyPrefix for their records will start with an `e` (`e00`, `e01`, ...).

```
select DurableId, QualifiedApiName, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, KeyPrefix 
from EntityDefinition 
where DurableId in ('01I0g000000Qe7F', '01I0g000000Qebo')
```

Alternatively, you do use one query to identify the DurableId's for the Platform Events defined in the org:

```
select DurableId, QualifiedApiName, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, KeyPrefix 
from EntityDefinition
where KeyPrefix like 'e%'
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of `EntityDefinition` at all. Thanks!